# numpy append, typeError: invalid type promotion

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I want to create a numpy ndarray with mixed data types. But I had problem appending another row to it.
My goal is to initalize k and keep adding rows to it in the future.

```
import numpy as np

k = np.ndarray((0,3), dtype=[('name', str), ('age', int), ('height', float)])
print(f'k datatype: {k.dtype}')
# k datatype: [('name', '<U'), ('age', '<i4'), ('height', '<f8')]
np.append(k, ['matt', 40, 180.5])
# TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

If I don't specify a dypte when creating k, then there is no error, but the columns in the ndarray all have the same data type (string).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The dtype has to match.

Comment: they do though, don't they? 'matt' is a string, 40 is an it and 180.5 is a float.

Comment: No.  `np.append` converts the list to an array before giving it to `concatenate.  Look at `np.array(['matt', 40, 180.5])`.  Its dtype does not match.  With compound dtype you have to specify the dtype.

Comment: The fact that you start with a (0,3) array suggests you intend to do this `append` repeatedlly.  Don't.  Collect values in a list, and create the array once.  And make sure it's a list of tuples.  Practice using this dtype to make an array without iterating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code. The first is that you should specify the `object` dtype for fields you intend to be variable-length strings.

The second is that `numpy` treats `lists` and `tuples` differently, in line with their conceptual origins. You need to convert the object you want to append to a struct-equivalent before appending.

This will work:

```
import numpy as np

k = np.ndarray((0,3), dtype=[('name', object), ('age', int), ('height', float)])
np.append(k, np.array(('matt', 40, 180.5), dtype=k.dtype))
```

Output:

```
array([('matt', 40, 180.5)],
      dtype=[('name', 'O'), ('age', '<i4'), ('height', '<f8')])
```