# How to calculate variance without type promotion error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, variance

I already referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172991/typeerror-invalid-type-promotion-when-appending-to-a-heterogeneous-numpy-arra) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55437498/numpy-append-typeerror-invalid-type-promotion) post. Don't mark it as duplicate please.

I am trying to compute the variance of all my dataframe columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'grade': np.random.choice(list('ABCD'),size=(20)),
                   'dash': np.random.choice(list('PQRS'),size=(20)),
                   'dumeel': np.random.choice(list('QWER'),size=(20)),
                   'dumma': np.random.choice((1234),size=(20)),
                   'target': np.random.choice([0,1],size=(20))
})
```

But I get the below error

```
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

I tried the below code

```
from feature_engine.encoding import OrdinalEncoder
rare_encoder = RareLabelEncoder(
tol=0.05,      # labels with frequencies < 'tol' will be grouped
n_categories=3,      # minimum categories required for encoding
variables = cat_list) # categorical features list
rare_encoder.fit(X_train)
train_t = rare_encoder.transform(X_train)
test_t = rare_encoder.transform(X_test)
ordinal_encoder = OrdinalEncoder(encoding_method='ordered',
                                 variables=cat_list)
ordinal_encoder.fit(train_t, y_train) # provide target to fit
ord_train_t = ordinal_encoder.transform(train_t)
ord_test_t = ordinal_encoder.transform(test_t)
sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.8 * (1 - .8)))
sel.fit_transform(ord_train_t)
```

`ord_train_t` is a dataframe where variables ordinal encoded.

Is there any other way to fix this error and drop low variance or zero variance columns based on threshold?

Comment: You show your original(?) dataframe but not the `ord_train_t` that you actually use in the sklearn(?) `VarianceThreshold` class instance.

Comment: @jjramsey - updated the code. the dataframe in question is just a sample dataframe

Comment: I applied rare label encoder, then ordinal encoder and then the variance computation

Comment: This still is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Ideally, you'd have only the data and code needed for someone else to reproduce the `TypeError`.

Comment: @jjramsey - am sorry what else I could share. I cannot share the dataset here. Apologies. If you want anything more, do let me know.

Comment: @I added more code to my post. Can help please?

Comment: The code you added isn't that helpful. You'll need to create a *minimal* dataset and *minimal* code that reproduces your error. If the error comes from `VarianceThreshold`, only show the dataset that you feed to `VarianceThreshold`. If the error came from an earlier step, such as `RareLabelEncoder` or `OrdinalEncoder`, only show the data fed to `RareLabelEncoder` or `OrdinalEncoder`. If you don't know what step generated the error, *find out*. It would also help to show the full traceback, not just the final error message.